# In my haml file, I want include a string from a yml file that has multiple links (in the same string)

Tags: internationalization, yaml, haml

This is what the rendered html would look like:

```
<p>The <a href="http://example.com/one.html">first link</a> and the <a href="http://example.com/two.html">second link</a> are both in this string.</p>
```

What should the yml and haml look like?

Note: I've figured out how to have a string with a single link, but I'm confused about how to set up multiple links.

I thought that the yaml might look like this:

```
example_text_html: "The <a href='%{link1}' target='_blank'>first link</a> and the <a href='%{link2}' target='_blank'>second link</a> are both in this string."
```

This is what I think the haml might look like:

```
%p
  = t(:example_text_html, link1:"https://www.example.com/one.html", link2:"http://example.com/two.html")
```

I got a syntax error when I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend keeping only the content of the translations themselves (ie "first link" etc) in the YAML locale files, and keep the link information in your views.  Also, since the content of "first link" and "second link" are likely to change in the locale, you will likely want seperate locale entries for them.

Putting this all together, you could do something like:

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  first_link: first link
  second_link: second link
  example_text_html: The %{first_link} and the %{second_link} are both in this string that could get translated to have very different grammar.
```

**app/views/your_view.html.haml**

```
%p
  = t('example_text_html',
      first_link: link_to(t('first_link'), 'http://example.com/one.html', target: :blank),
      second_link: link_to(t('second_link'), 'http://example.com/two.html', target: :blank))
```

If that looks a bit long, you could create some helpers to clean it up.  Perhaps something like:

**app/helpers/your_helper.rb**

```
def first_link
  link_to(t('first_link'), 'http://example.com/one.html', target: :blank)
end

def second_link
  link_to(t('second_link'), 'http://example.com/two.html', target: :blank)
end
```

So then you could refactor the view to look something like:

**app/views/your_view.html.haml**

```
%p
  = t('example_text_html', first_link: first_link, second_link: second_link)
```

Comment: I'll try this! Thanks!!

Comment: do I have to add the _html part to the variables?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean add `_html` to the YAML keys?  You shouldn't need to since for this solution, since there is no HTML contained in the values for those keys.  See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations) for more info about using safe HTML translations in Rails.

Comment: ...I did need to add the _html to the main variable name to get it to render the html. Will you edit your answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer? Also, I didn't use the helper... that's a little confusing in this context at this point. Maybe you could add it at the end of the answer? just a suggestion. I think I would need to create that file from scratch, right?

Comment: we commented at the same time :)

Comment: when I wasn't using the _html it was rendering the <a> tags and the spelled out urls

Comment: Ah right, yes, since you'd be passing HTML in to `example_text`, it would need to be renamed as `example_text_html` to be considered safe to render.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: oh wait.. that's because of me.

Comment: This is my haml:  ` %p
          = t(:example_text_html, first_link: link_to(t('first_link'), 'http://example.com/one.html', target: :blank),second_link: link_to(t('second_link'), 'http://stackoverflow.com', target: :blank))

Comment: and this is my yaml:   first_link: first link
  second_link: second link
  example_text_html: The %{first_link} and the %{second_link} are both in this string that could get translated to have very different grammar.

Comment: @pixelfairy looks good!  I've edited my answer to reflect having `_html` at the end of a YAML key that will have strings with HTML passed into it.

Comment: you say I don't need the "_html" but I couldn't get it to render properly without it. Otherwise, this works great! Thanks again!!

Comment: commented at the same time again :)
I'll mark it as answered.